# Problema ao fazer upload de uma foto para um servidor web

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-service

Olá! estou com um problema para fazer upload de uma foto tirada de um aplicativo android para um servidor web. No servidor local ele envia normalmente a foto, já no servidor web, ele envia apenas uma foto e só envia outra se limpar o cache do aplicativo no android. Segue abaixo o código responsável por tirar a foto e enviar para o servidor. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            getFileUri();
            i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, file_uri);
            startActivityForResult(i, 10);
        }
    });
}

private void getFileUri() {

    image_name = "teste123.jpeg";
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            + File.separator + image_name
    );

    file_uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        new Encode_image().execute();
    }
}

private class Encode_image extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file_uri.getPath());
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        bitmap.recycle();

        byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
        encoded_string = Base64.encodeToString(array, 0);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        makeRequest();
    }
}

private void makeRequest() {
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

            StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://teste.com.br/servidor/package/photo/connection.php",

            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("encoded_string",encoded_string);
            map.put("image_name",image_name);

            return map;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(request);
    Toast.makeText(CarActivity.this, "Foto enviada com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Cara, talvez seja porque você está colocando o nome fixo para a imagem. Então quando você for tirar uma nova foto, vai constar que já existe a imagem. Tente definir o nome da imagem dinamicamente, como por exemplo, peque a hora atual que tirou a foto e coloque como nome da imagem.

Comment: Eu já tentei isso e não deu certo. E tambem se fosse isso ele não funcionaria localmente, onde nesse caso ele substitui a foto pois já tem uma com o mesmo nome.